# SQLServerException: Login failed for user token-identified principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I am connecting to Azure SQL database using managed identity but facing this error, what else am I missing there guys?

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''

- Java 17
- SQL Driver 9.4.1.jre8

Connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;encrypt=true;databaseName=simple;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;msiClientId=[Client id of the managed Identity myinstance];
```

I have enabled Azure AD for Azure SQL server, turn on System assigned for VM. In User assigned tab, I add my managed Identity.

In Azure SQL, I've added users with the name of my Virtual Machine (testMSSQL) and the name of the managed Identity (myinstance) using this statement:

```
CREATE USER testMSSQL FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER testMSSQL;

CREATE USER myinstance FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER myinstance;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you enable login auditing and confirm which login is failing. Everything looks setup correctly, I can only assume it's not using the login you think it is. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/527948/need-help-tracking-down-azure-sql-error-message-lo BTW i have never had to use a client id to connect via system identity. Maybe it's a java / VM thing

Comment: Sometimes a simple firwall issue also throws simillar issues. Is your firewall config on azure sql allowing access from VM?

Comment: My mistake when all of your points are passed but my connection string has an error, it should be `database` not `databaseName`, cause the wrong param so it connects to `master` db as default, which the user does not have the authorization, hence login failed exception is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure the Azure Active Directory user is created on the Azure SQL Database, because sometimes by default we connect to the master database when we use tools like SSMS to connect to Azure SQL. In addition, please make sure you created the Azure SQL user by taking in consideration all the permissions and steps described on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell&view=azuresql#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities). Add the Azure SQL user to the following roles and try again:  added to the db_datareader, db_datawriter and db_ddladmin.

Try the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server” set as Yes in the firewall and virtual networks settings in your Azure SQL Database.

Comment: My mistake when all of your points are passed but my connection string has an error, it should be `database` not `databaseName`, cause the wrong param so it connects to `master` db as default, which the user does not have the authorization, hence login failed exception is thrown

Comment: Connecting to master is very common. I am glad you have it resolved quickly.

Comment: Is it truly necessary for the user to assume `db_datareader` which will read all tables, all schemas in db? Is there any specific system table that AD user needs access cause this seems too broad? @Alberto

Comment: No is not necessary to add the user to any fixed database role. You can create a custom role (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and assign the user to it. Give the role only the permissions the user need.